# HtmlUnit wait for redirect

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm having following scenario I need to implement in `HtmlUnit`:

-I click button 
-Im getting redirected to page www.page.pl/result 
-I need to wait few seconds and then I'm getting redirected to www.anotherpage.pl/auth_code=qwe123

The problem is, once I'm getting to /result page, I can't get out of it to next one. There are no manual actions there, I just need to wait until redirect happens

Here is my `WebClient`

```
private WebClient initWebClient() {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    return webClient;
}
```

And how I'm trying to accomplish this, I'v tried several ways, including `Thread.sleep()` already...

```
 HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
 page.getForms().get(0).getButtonByName("submit").click(); // Redirects me to /result
 webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
 webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 page.refresh(); //I'm still on /result, while I need to be on completely new page by now
```

Comment: Please post the (html) code of page you are getting from the first redirect (www.page.pl/result).

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else have similar issue, I found solution

```
    webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent webWindowEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent webWindowEvent) {
            if (webWindowEvent.getNewPage() != null) {
                // do what you need to do with webWindowEvent.getNewPage().getUrl();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent webWindowEvent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey man, please, how exactly this example works? Can you post the complete code please? I am having the same issue...